# How to load a Apache Commons Math RealMatrix

Tags: apache, math, matrix, io

It is overly complicated to load a matrix with Apache Common Math, using the utility: 
   MatrixUtils.deserializeRealMatrix(Object instance, String fieldName, ObjectInputStream ois)

Since you have to implement a new class to store the result of "fieldname".

Do you know of a better way? All I want to do is:

RealMatrix A = loadMatrix("myrealmatrix.dat");

Comment: This should really be a standard function.

Answer (score 1):

The serialization / deserialization methods are for Java object serialization.  The simplest way to load a `RealMatrix` from a file is to use code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8045342/2251270) (modified to handle whatever format you are using to represent the source data) to load the file data into a `double[][]`array and then use the `createRealMatrix` method in `MatrixUtils`.